# manage Tableview properties from setting view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiswitch

I have `UITabBarViewController` which has 2 views. 
The first view has a `UITableView` which has 1 section and 5 rows.
The second view has a `UITableView` as well which has a settings options like UISwitches. 
My question is how can I show and hide or remove a cell from first view by using UISwitches on the settings view? Thanks in advance.

**edit**

this video explain what i am trying to do (check the app view)

[Press Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6PQojyecKM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accomplish this by using NSNotificationCenter

in your firstView you can write a code like:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(modifyCell:) name:@"modifyCell" object:nil];
 }

   //make sure this is declared in your .h
 -(void)modifyCell:(NSNotification*)notif
  {
    if (notif) {
              //cellindex to modify
    NSString *cellIndex = [[notif userInfo] objectForKey:@"index"];
    [yourDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:[cellIndex intValue]]
    [yourTableView reloadData];
     }
  }
```

in your secondView:

```
  -(void)switchChanged
  {
     NSNotificationCenter *ncSubject = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
     NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"indexNum",@"index", nil];
      [ncSubject postNotificationName:@"modifyCell" object:nil userInfo:dict];
      [ncSubject removeObserver:self];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reload your tableview after each UISwitch change. Such as:
- you set a delegate from your UISwitch to your UITabBarViewController (or the class which controls the events)
- you should store your tableview's cells' number in a variable
- this variable will change after each UISwitch change
- after the variable change, you should reload the tableview

Comment: i did that , nothing happend :(

Comment: Please, verify if the changing method appeals, when you change the UISwitch's state, with a simple break point or NSLog. Does it appeal?

Comment: method works well, but nothing changed also . please check edit video that explain what i am trying to do . thanks again

Comment: At the [tableview reload] method, does the tableview reload method appeal?

Comment: you mean [tableview reloadData] ?? nothing happend also

Comment: Yes, reloadData, sry. So the tableview reloading method doesn't appeal? Then the problem is here :) Check if it's connected with the correct tableview :) I think here should be a small typo or sthg similar.

Answer (score 1):

In the viewWillAppear method of the table view controller I would check whether the setting has been changed or not. If it has changed then I would redraw the cell by calling its the reloadData method. 
Sometimes it is recommended to call reloadData through performSelectorOnMainThread:

```
[ self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

And your data loading methods (numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.) will have to consider the settings value accordingly.